# Why is Excess-K used instead of Two's complement in exponent IEEE754

Tags: binary, ieee-754

IEEE 754 stored exponent using `Excess K` forma, which is also known as `Offset Binary representation`. I've googled and it seems that it's just one of formats to represent negative binary numbers. I'm wondering why `two's complement` form is not used for that purpose?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a programming problem.

Comment: where do you suggest to migrate it to?

Comment: I'm not sure; it's a question about decisions made by a committee 40 years ago. It's probably an interesting story, but since IEEE754 math is done by hardware now there's not any practical reason for it to be different than it is.

Comment: [Possibly of interest.](https://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/754story.html)

Comment: @Pointy, I see, ok, thanks for the reference, I'll check it out. Do you suggest I delete the question?

Comment: I don't see any reason to delete it. It may get closed eventually. Off-topic questions aren't necessarily bad things, they're just off-topic :)

Comment: [There's also this older question which I think might be exactly the same.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864749/why-do-we-bias-the-exponent-of-a-floating-point-number) The answer on that one is clear as a bell, and it's probably something I knew at some point :)

Comment: @Pointy, thanks, that answer that you linked is probably a good read so maybe mark this one as duplicate?

Comment: @Pointy, [here is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2835476/2545680) another good one that answers this question.